# Form Model Binding - Not populating form field value

Tags: php, forms, laravel, laravel-4

I'm new to Laravel but getting there with it. I've got an issue with Form Model binding, I've set the form model to bind and set the data in my Database, But the field is not populating to match.

I suspect, I've missed something obvious, Although not sure.

My current code is :

**Route**

```
Route::get('admin/user/bank-details', array('as' => 'bank.edit', function()
{
    $user_id = Auth::id();

    $bank_details = Banks::whereRaw("(user_id = '".$user_id."')")->get();

    // Return Our View...
    return View::make('user.update_bank')
               ->with('bank_details', $bank_details);
}));
```

**View**

```
{ Form::model($bank_details, array('route' => 'bank.edit')) }}
 <div class="form-group">
  <label for="bank_sortcode">Bank Sortcode</label>
  {{ Form::text('bank_sortcode', null, array('class' => 'form-control sortcode', 'placeholder' => 'Bank Sort Code')) }}
 </div><!-- /.form-group -->
{{ Form::close() }}
```

**Model**

```
class Banks extends \Eloquent {

    // Don't forget to fill this array
    protected $fillable = array('bank_sortcode');

    use SoftDeletingTrait;

    protected $dates = ['deleted_at'];

    protected $primaryKey = "bank_id";
}
```

My Database table contains a field titled bank_sortcode and its value is currently set as "20-20-20"

Thanks

Comment: A couple of things I've noticed. You don't have a controller. was this your intention? Further, you don't need to use whereRaw, just use ```Banks::where('user_id', $user_id)->get()```

Comment: Hi @wiesson I do have a controller, But it only contains the method that handles the post data. Have changed the where clause to match your suggestion

Comment: take a look at this lesson: https://laracasts.com/series/laravel-5-fundamentals/episodes/18 Maybe this solves your question already. If not, I will help you with the answer.

Comment: @wiesson I see that laracast is mainly Laravel 5.

Comment: Oh, I think I'm wrong - I thought about route-model-binding! But you are looking for Form model binding. Laracasts also provides (free) lessons for laravel 4.X.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can only populate a form with a single model. So change

```
$bank_details = Banks::whereRaw("(user_id = '".$user_id."')")->get();
```

to this

```
$bank_details = Banks::where('user_id', $user_id)->first();
```

Using this function you only get one record (not an array of records) - so it should work then.

p.s. you should only ever use `raw` eloquent queries in very very very raw circumstances. Otherwise you are creating security risks unnecessarily.

Comment: Hi @The Shift Exchange appreciate that answer. That did the trick. Makes sense the ->first() parameter. I didnt' realise you could pass an alternate value into the eloquent query without it being a DB Raw query.